# DocuSignAPI nuget c# REST package: UpdateRecipients & UpdateDocuments Tabs not added when adding a new doc to an existing envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the nuget c# REST package.  When I try to add a document with new recipients to an existing envelope, the recipients & the document show in the envelope but there are no tabs associated with the new doc even though the tabs are listed for the new recipients when I call UpdateRecipients.

I've checked to make sure the DocID matches in the tabs with the new DocID sent in the EnvelopeDefinition to UpdateDocuments & all the other data seems to be correct but no tabs show for the new recipients.

I've tried this passing in just the 2 new recipients or passing in the whole list of recipients (3 previous + 2 new).  In both cases all the recipients return a success message from UpdateRecipients but no tabs are added.

Here is some of my code.

```
            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();

            foreach (DSDocumentIN docIN in documents)
            {

                // Add a document to the envelope
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.Name = docIN.Name;
                doc.DocumentBase64 = docIN.FileBase64;
                doc.DocumentId = docIN.DocID;

                envDef.Documents.Add(doc);
            }

            int iCounter = 1;

            List<Signer> signerList = new List<Signer>();

            List<DSSigner> fullSignerList = new List<DSSigner>();
            fullSignerList = GetDSSigners(existingEnvelopeId);
            foreach (DSSigner newSigner in signers)
            {
                fullSignerList.Add(newSigner);
            }

            foreach (DSSigner s in fullSignerList)
            {
                Signer docSigner = new Signer();
                docSigner.Email = s.Email;
                docSigner.Name = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName;
                docSigner.RoleName = s.Role;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RecipientId))
                    docSigner.RecipientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                else
                    docSigner.RecipientId = s.RecipientId;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RoutingOrder))
                    docSigner.RoutingOrder = iCounter.ToString();
                else
                    docSigner.RoutingOrder = s.RoutingOrder;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.State))
                    docSigner.Status = "Created";
                else
                    docSigner.Status = s.State;


                docSigner.Tabs = AllTabs(docSigner, documents);

                signerList.Add(docSigner);
                iCounter++;
            }

            envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = signerList;

            RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = apiInstance.UpdateRecipients(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, envDef.Recipients);


            EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocumentsOptions UpdateDocOptions = new EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocumentsOptions();
            UpdateDocOptions.applyDocumentFields = "True";  // string | When true, Document fields can be added or modified while adding or modifying envelope documents. (optional)  

            // Adds one or more documents to an existing envelope document.
            EnvelopeDocumentsResult result = apiInstance.UpdateDocuments(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, envDef, UpdateDocOptions);
            Debug.WriteLine(result);

            //Get recipients to find RecipientIdGuid (which becomes RecipientId when sending). RecipientId is key field in db. -- DocuSign does not appear to have this RecipientIdGuid/RecipientId documented
            Recipients recips = apiInstance.ListRecipients(accountId, existingEnvelopeId);
```

06/12/18 UPDATE: Currently, I'm adding the new doc & then the recipients. I've included a link to the logs for this approach:
[DocuSign Log](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AselpXKmf_KUgTwHOTlYlpPYoVKb)

(see specifically 04_OK_AddDocumentsToEnvelope.txt & 03_OK_UpdateEnvelopeRecipients.txt)

Comment: Some additional info: I'm using the nuget package for c# to call the DocuSign api so UpdateRecipients = EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipients & UpdateDocuments = EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocuments.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this figured out.

Going to clean it up & make sure it is working as desired & then I'll post more details here.

06/13/2018 UPDATE:
This answer is specifically for using the nuget c# REST package.  Since the tabs are part of the Recipient object, I expected that including the tabs in the recipient object & then adding the recipient to the envelope would work.  However this is not the case when calling the UpdateRecipients method.  The new recipients get added but no new tabs.  Instead the tabs must be added separately.

Also interesting was the names of the functions that had to be called as follows:
Add new doc = UpdateDocuments
Add new recipients = UpdateRecipients
Add new tabs = **Create**Tabs

There are probably other ways that work but here is the meat of the code that works for me:

```
    public string AddDocumentsToEnvelope(List<DSDocumentIN> documents, List<DSSigner> signers, string clientAppNo, int PDFRequestID, string envelopeID)
    {

        string username = "randys@balboacapital.com";
        string password = "555Tmppwd";
        string integratorKey = "321e15cb-89a1-4958-a444-6b2d33fc7005";


        string retEnvelopeID = "";
        ExceptionDispatchInfo exInfo = null;

        try
        {

            var pdfDocCtrl = new BalboaLeaseCL.PDFDocController();
            var apiInstance = new EnvelopesApi();

            string existingEnvelopeId = envelopeID;

            // initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

            // we will retrieve this from the login API call
            string accountId = null;

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // STEP 1: LOGIN API        
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // login call is available in the authentication api 
            AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
            accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

            // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
            string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };
            apiClient = new ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);

            EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();

            foreach (DSDocumentIN docIN in documents)
            {

                // Add a document to the envelope
                Document doc = new Document();
                doc.Name = docIN.Name;
                doc.DocumentBase64 = docIN.FileBase64;
                doc.DocumentId = docIN.DocID;

                envDef.Documents.Add(doc);
            }

            int iCounter = 1;

            List<Signer> signerList = new List<Signer>();

            List<DSSigner> fullSignerList = new List<DSSigner>();
            fullSignerList = GetDSSigners(existingEnvelopeId);

            foreach (DSSigner newSigner in signers)
            {
                fullSignerList.Add(newSigner);
            }

            foreach (DSSigner s in fullSignerList)
            {
                Signer docSigner = new Signer();
                docSigner.Email = s.Email;
                docSigner.Name = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName;
                docSigner.RoleName = s.Role;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RecipientId))
                    docSigner.RecipientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                else
                    docSigner.RecipientId = s.RecipientId;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.RoutingOrder))
                    docSigner.RoutingOrder = iCounter.ToString();
                else
                    docSigner.RoutingOrder = s.RoutingOrder;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.State))
                    docSigner.Status = "Created";
                else
                    docSigner.Status = s.State;


                docSigner.Tabs = AllTabs(docSigner, documents);

                signerList.Add(docSigner);
                iCounter++;
            }

            envDef.Recipients = new Recipients();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            envDef.Recipients.Signers = signerList;



            EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocumentsOptions UpdateDocOptions = new EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocumentsOptions();
            UpdateDocOptions.applyDocumentFields = "True";  // string | When true, Document fields can be added or modified while adding or modifying envelope documents. (optional)  

            // Adds one or more documents to an existing envelope 
            EnvelopeDocumentsResult result = apiInstance.UpdateDocuments(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, envDef, UpdateDocOptions);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.EnvelopeId))
                throw new DocuSignAPIException("No EnvelopeID returned.");
            else
                retEnvelopeID = result.EnvelopeId;

            //Adds recipients to envelope (but won't create tabs)
            RecipientsUpdateSummary recipientsUpdateSummary = apiInstance.UpdateRecipients(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, envDef.Recipients);



            foreach (DSSigner newSigner in signers)
            {
                foreach (Signer s in envDef.Recipients.Signers)
                {
                    if (newSigner.RecipientId.Equals(s.RecipientId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        //Adds the tabs for the recipients for the new doc
                        apiInstance.CreateTabs(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, s.RecipientId, s.Tabs);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have created an envelope, then you need to make below calls to add a document and recipients with correct tabs on the document, I have JSON code sample req only, cannot test with CSharp code, but you find out exact call for the same:

## To add a document, call below endpoint,

no need to add recipients in this call, just add document

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/2
```

with below **headers:**

```
Accept:application/json
Authorization:Bearer <AccessToken>
Content-Type:application/pdf
Content-Disposition:file; filename="Cross Company Guaranty"; fileExtension=pdf; documentId=2
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
```

**Body:**

base64bytes

Both `UpdateDocuments()` and `UpdateDocument()` can add document to the envelope.

## To add recipients and its tabs you need to call below endpoint,

instead of [EnvelopeRecipients: update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update), it should be [Envelopes: update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update) with a query parameter `advanced_update=true`

PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?advanced_update=true

**Body:**

```
{
"recipients": {
    "signers": [{
        "email": "FakeTempEmailAddressRequired@bccfaketemp.com",
        "name": "Mary GS",
        "recipientId": "78647ecb-ee2e-4910-92ef-c9bf18710657",
        "roleName": "Guarantor_Signor",
        "routingOrder": "4",
        "status": "Created",
        "tabs": {
            "dateSignedTabs": [],
            "initialHereTabs": [],
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "documentId": "2",
                "optional": "false",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "78647ecb-ee2e-4910-92ef-c9bf18710657",
                "scaleValue": "0.9",
                "tabOrder": "2",
                "xPosition": "60",
                "yPosition": "343"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "disableAutoSize": "true",
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "height": 10,
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "78647ecb-ee2e-4910-92ef-c9bf18710657",
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "SealDate",
                "tabOrder": "1",
                "validationMessage": "Please enter valid date using \"mm/dd/yyyy\" format",
                "validationPattern": "^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/]?[0-9]{4})*$",
                "width": 100,
                "xPosition": "248",
                "yPosition": "319"
            },
            {
                "disableAutoSize": "true",
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "height": 10,
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "78647ecb-ee2e-4910-92ef-c9bf18710657",
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "Guarantor_SignorTitle",
                "tabOrder": "3",
                "validationMessage": "",
                "validationPattern": "",
                "width": 210,
                "xPosition": "71",
                "yPosition": "408"
            },
            {
                "disableAutoSize": "true",
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "height": 10,
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "78647ecb-ee2e-4910-92ef-c9bf18710657",
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "Guarantor_SignorTitle",
                "tabOrder": "4",
                "validationMessage": "",
                "validationPattern": "",
                "width": 210,
                "xPosition": "114",
                "yPosition": "522"
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "email": "FakeTempEmailAddressRequired@bccfaketemp.com",
        "name": "Tony GW",
        "recipientId": "259e95e8-b774-47c1-b2dd-acab0d3b965e",
        "roleName": "GuarantorWitness",
        "routingOrder": "5",
        "status": "Created",
        "tabs": {
            "dateSignedTabs": [{
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "259e95e8-b774-47c1-b2dd-acab0d3b965e",
                "tabOrder": "4",
                "xPosition": "80",
                "yPosition": "660"
            }],
            "initialHereTabs": [],
            "signHereTabs": [{
                "documentId": "2",
                "optional": "false",
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "259e95e8-b774-47c1-b2dd-acab0d3b965e",
                "scaleValue": "0.9",
                "tabOrder": "2",
                "xPosition": "84",
                "yPosition": "579"
            }],
            "textTabs": [{
                "disableAutoSize": "true",
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "height": 10,
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "259e95e8-b774-47c1-b2dd-acab0d3b965e",
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "GuarantorWitnessTitle",
                "tabOrder": "1",
                "validationMessage": "",
                "validationPattern": "",
                "width": 200,
                "xPosition": "425",
                "yPosition": "464"
            },
            {
                "disableAutoSize": "true",
                "documentId": "2",
                "fontSize": "Size8",
                "height": 10,
                "pageNumber": "1",
                "recipientId": "259e95e8-b774-47c1-b2dd-acab0d3b965e",
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "GuarantorWitnessTitle",
                "tabOrder": "3",
                "validationMessage": "",
                "validationPattern": "",
                "width": 210,
                "xPosition": "80",
                "yPosition": "645"
            }]
        }
    }]
    }
}
```

`Update` method should work, but make sure to pass/set `advancedUpdate` as true in  `UpdateOptions` parameters

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I have a couple of follow-up comments: (1) The doc that I'm adding is an additional doc to the envelope.  I'm adding it to the envelope for the first time so persist_tabs=true doesn't seem like it would be the correct parameter.  The doc doesn't exist previously.  (2) For your "Other option", I am already using EnvelopesApi.UpdateDocumentOptions = true with this line from my code: EnvelopeDocumentsResult result = apiInstance.UpdateDocuments(accountId, existingEnvelopeId, envDef, UpdateDocOptions);

Comment: Reading your qs, and call I thought that you are updating the document. So you are just adding a document, then adding recipient and its tabs on the added document?

Comment: Yes.  I'm adding a doc which has new recipients to an existing envelope.  The doc and the new recipients show in the envelope but the tabs are not there when I try to sign.  The tab information is in the JSON log & I do get a success message back for the new recipients.

Comment: Can you please capture logs generated when you are calling DS API, youc an capture logs by following steps as explained [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), it seems you are adding documents after you have added the recipients and its tabs. Also your code does not show how you are adding tabs on the document. So capture logs and can you share the req/resp of the API logs with detailed steps, which call was triggered first and so on...

Comment: Yes, I check the logs frequently.  Also, I've tried adding the recipients before adding the new doc & I've tried adding the doc first & then the new recipients.  Surprisingly, there is no noticeable difference in these approaches.  Currently, I'm adding the new doc & then the recipients.  I'll attached the logs for this approach.

Comment: Update my answer with proper code, I tested and its working fine for me

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  Your answer may be correct too, but I posted my solution for anyone using the C# REST pkg & I added that to the title header.  Hopefully it helps someone else in the future.